# How to parse text into a struct using boost::spirit?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm learning `boost::spirit`, and I'm trying to read and parse some text into a struct.

For example, `"2: 4.6"` is parsed as int `2` and double `4.6` in my `TestStruct` below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct TestStruct {
  int myint;
  double mydouble;
  TestStruct() {}
  TestStruct(std::pair<int,double> p) : myint(p.first), mydouble(p.second) {}
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, TestStruct(), Skipper> {
  MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(mystruct) {
    mystruct0 = qi::int_ >> ":" >> qi::double_;
    mystruct = mystruct0;
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<int,double>(), Skipper> mystruct0;
  qi::rule<Iterator, TestStruct(), Skipper> mystruct;
};

int main() {
  typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
  std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
  It it(std::cin), end; // input example: "2: 3.4"                                                                              

  MyGrammar<It, qi::space_type> gr;
  TestStruct ts;
  if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, gr, qi::space, ts) && it == end)
    std::cout << ts.myint << ", " << ts.mydouble << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It works nicely, but I'm wondering how this code can be simplified?

For example, I would like to get rid of the `mystruct0` grammar rule, which is only there to mark the type `std::pair<int,double>`, which is then used to automatically construct the `TestStruct` object from the `mystruct` rule.

I'd also like to be able to get rid of the `TestStruct` constructor from `std::pair`, if possible.

So, can the following code somehow made to be compiled? That would be a much nicer solution:

```
struct TestStruct {
  int myint;
  double mydouble;
  TestStruct() {}
  TestStruct(int i, double d) : myint(i), mydouble(d) {}
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, TestStruct(), Skipper> {
  MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(mystruct) {
    mystruct = qi::int_ >> ":" >> qi::double_;
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator, TestStruct(), Skipper> mystruct;
};

int main() {
  typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;
  std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
  It it(std::cin), end; // input example: "2: 3.4"                                                                              

  MyGrammar<It, qi::space_type> gr;
  TestStruct ts;
  if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, gr, qi::space, ts) && it == end)
    std::cout << ts.myint << ", " << ts.mydouble << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler says:

```
boost_1_49_0/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:123: 
error: no matching function for call to ‘TestStruct::TestStruct(const int&)’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that code can be compiled. In fact, you can do without the constructors: the default (compiler generated) constructor is fine.

All you need to do is adapt your struct as a fusion sequence. (As a bonus, this works for karma as well.) 
***This is precisely the magic that made `std::pair` work in the first place.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct TestStruct {
    int myint;
    double mydouble;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(TestStruct, (int, myint)(double, mydouble));

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, TestStruct(), Skipper> {
    MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(mystruct) {
        mystruct = qi::int_ >> ":" >> qi::double_;
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, TestStruct(), Skipper> mystruct;
};

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    const std::string input("2: 3.4");
    It it(input.begin()), end(input.end());

    MyGrammar<It, qi::space_type> gr;
    TestStruct ts;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, gr, qi::space, ts) && it == end)
        std::cout << ts.myint << ", " << ts.mydouble << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To be able to parse values "sequentially" into a struct, you need to transform it into a `fusion` tuple, as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html).

In your case, this means you need to

1. Include the necessary header

   ```
   #include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
   ```
2. Use the fusion-adapt struct macro. Best place it *right after the declaration of `TestStruct`*:

   ```
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
           TestStruct,
           (int,myint)
           (double,mydouble)
        )
   ```

With these two changes, your simplified version compiles and yields the desired results. Not sure if it is really much simpler now – but if you plan to add further members to your struct, it's a good starting point as it may help simplify things in the future.

I don't see any other major changes you could make to make the program simpler.